# Reading Bitmap file

Tags: c++, file, winapi, struct, bitmap

I try to read a bitmap file. This my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <string>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma pack(1)
struct header
{
    char header[2];
    int32_t filesize;
    int16_t reser;
    int16_t reser1;
    int32_t dataoffset;
};

struct infoheader
{
    int32_t headersize;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t plans;
    int16_t bpp;
    int32_t compression;
    int32_t datasize;
    int32_t re;
    int32_t ve;
    int32_t color;
    int32_t importantcolor;
};

struct  PIxel
{
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
    unsigned char R;
};

int main()
{
    header h;
    infoheader info;
    PIxel *p;
    ifstream file("bmp2.bmp", ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
        file.read((char*)&h, sizeof(h));
        file.read((char*)&info, sizeof(info));
        cout << info.width << " " << info.height << " " << h.filesize << " " << info.bpp << endl;
        int pa = info.width % 4;
        int size = info.width * info.height * (info.bpp / 3) + pa * info.height;
        char* arr = new char[size];
        file.read(arr, size);
        char* temp = arr;
        int sizep = info.height * info.width;
        p = new PIxel[sizep];

        for (int i = 0; i < info.height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
            {
                p[i * info.height + j].B = *(temp++);
                p[i * info.height + j].G = *(temp++);
                p[i * info.height + j].R = *(temp++);
                //p = p + 3;
            }
            p += pa;
        }

        HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
        HDC hdc = GetDC(consoleWindow);
        for (int i = 0; i < info.height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
            {
                PIxel m = p[i * info.height + j];
                SetPixel(hdc, i, j, RGB(m.R, m.G, m.B));
            }
        }
        ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, hdc);
    }
}
```

It works but the image on my console is not right...

[image]

Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the per line padding. Although your code appears to be using the padding.

Comment: I think `p += pa;` is wrong. You want to advance `temp` by the padding not `p`. `p` is the destination. The source is what has the padding.

Comment: Also it is not a good idea to draw on console window.

Comment: Maybe the idea was to provide a background for the console. However I don't believe that can work as expected and I believe is for a different question if that was the desired purpose of this application.

Comment: why you not use `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, `BITMAPINFOHEADER` and `RGBTRIPLE`. you hardcode 24bpp bmp. you code will not work with another bpp. why not use `CreateDIBSection` and `BitBlt`

Comment: That is a good question. If this was some type of academic requirement to read a bitmap directly instead of using the winapi support I can understand why you would want to do this.

Comment: The [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec) comes with a [bitmap decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec#native-codecs) so that we don't have to deal with those internals, and get them wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int size = info.width * info.height * (info.bpp / 3) + pa * info.height;
> ```

The above calculation for size is incorrect. Bits per pixel should be divided by 8. The indexing in the for loops is also wrong. It ends ups multiplying height x height.

Also `SetPixel(... i, j ...)` should be changed to `SetPixel(... j, i ...)` since `i` in your case, refers to the y-axis.

As mentioned in previous answer, the padding has to be fixed too.

Note that you can use `LoadImage` and other Windows GDI functions to open and draw bitmaps.

```
int size = (info.width * (info.bpp / 8) + pa) * info.height;
...
for(int i = info.height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
    {
        int index = i * (info.width) + j;
        p[index].B = *(temp++);
        p[index].G = *(temp++);
        p[index].R = *(temp++);
    }
    temp += pa;
}

for(int i = 0; i < info.height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
    {
        int index = i * (info.width) + j;
        PIxel m = p[index];
        SetPixel(hdc, j, i, RGB(m.R, m.G, m.B));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have your padding adjustment on the wrong pointer. The padding is present on the source image. You don't want it on the destination image. You are accounting for the padding with `p += pa;`  you should instead replace this line with `temp += pa` to account for the padding of the source image.